# Best way to make methods easily callable and configurable by third party

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with several self-contained classes and methods. For example, I have:

a FileDownloader class that has multiple different methods that download files based on passing in a URL or multiple URLs

a DataTransformations class that has multiple methods that transform data depending on what is necessary for a given operation

a FileWriter class that writes some data to some kind of file type or file format

etc.

I have all of these classes as .cs files under the same solution. I can consider the order of executions for some specific operation and call the methods from MAIN in the correct order and it produces the output that I expect. I will eventually, however, need to call some or all of these methods in many different configurations for several different processes and I don't know how to do that. I know how to pass in configuration through command line arguments, but even that requires the specific order and number of methods called stays the same between processes. This is not tenable because I will not need to download files in some instances and I will not need to transform data in some instances etc. I am very new to .NET development and I have not yet wrapped my head around how to truly decouple these classes from each other. Do I have to deploy a different solution for each class? I would like to just be able to say "call file downloader with these parameters" and then "perform data transformations based on these parameters" basically like steps in an execution job.

Comment: I would consider that a workflow, perhaps a workflow class would be useful in which the workflow class encapsulates the calls to the other class methods.

Comment: Nothing you've said suggests that your classes are coupled to each other. It sounds like part of the problem is that you want to write one piece of code that might do any number of different things based on configuration values. Instead, write a class or method that does one thing. Then write a class or method that does another thing. Keep them completely separate. Write them as if there was no command line. Leave the command line out of the picture. When that code works you can write something that takes command line arguments and decides which of those classes or methods to use.

Comment: I agree. I think they are completely separate. I just don't understand how to call them if they aren't explicitly listed in some order in the Main(string[] args) method like this:

FileDownloader.DownloadFile(downloadURLs, workingDirectory, downloadExtension, true);

DataTransformer.NcciTransformer(combinedOutput, schemaFilePathTransformed, outputFilePathTransformed, conn, headerLinesToSkip, separator);

Comment: This is a reasonable question but might not be a good fit for this site because it's so close to the fundamentals of how to write code. (If that sounds negative somehow it's not my intent.) I'd start by imagining a few concrete scenarios: I want to download and transform. I want to download, not transform, etc. Write a method for each of those scenarios. Get some of it working. It will be messy, but that's okay. Then write a method that takes the command line arguments and figures out which of those methods to call.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help me here. I apologize if the question is overly broad. I have this solution effectively completely developed. So I can call some or all of these methods from MAIN in any order that I want and it works. My problem is that I am going to need to call these methods with all of those different configurations in from different jobs for different processes. I'm sorry if I'm being dense here. I am just wondering if there is a way to accommodate all of that? Or can each solution only perform one configuration of executions?

Answer (score 0):

Dirty Answer, Compile as a library and then add a reference in whatever project you want to use those methods for. you can then call the methods by name (LibraryName).MethodName(Parameters). of course you will need to always have that DLL in whatever other project need access. if you have any questions on how to do this let me know.

Comment: So does that mean basically turning the solution into a Nuget pacakge and then each process would be its own solution that downloads that nuget and calls the methods?

Comment: More it  means turning it into a dll. of course in doing so, you have all of your methods in one tight little packages. and there is code to call methods by string name, no you could just generate those strings at runti,e